# React Native: how to get emulator of iPad with iOS 14.0?

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, emulation

I got a report from the App Store that my React Native app crashed when testing on an iPad running iOS 14.0. When I run `xcrun simctl list devices` to see a list of available emulators, it lists the following iPads that are available:

```
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (859B2DFB-CEB6-4212-968C-4B78EA38A3E3) (Shutdown) 
iPad (7th generation) (07102BF3-FDFC-4A13-B419-8E949AB30F7C) (Shutdown) 
iPad Pro (11-inch) (72F6F096-1905-433A-89E0-BB320BF1FA52) (Shutdown) 
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) (301FC9C6-C401-4088-ACA6-59A300315198) (Shutdown) 
iPad Air (3rd generation) (78C3FAB7-B2E1-4E63-90D5-070DD12CF96D) (Shutdown)
```

It doesn't indicate what version of iOS any of these is running.

**What I Want To Know:** Is there a way to get an emulator of an iPad running iOS 14.0? Would I need a specific emulator for that, or could I use any of these ones listed, and change some setting on them to get them to run iOS 14.0?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do this:

**1 way:**

- Launch an emulator
- right click on the Icon in the AppBar
- Choose "Device"
- Here you can choose the OS version and then the Emulator type...

**2 way:**

- Open your project in Xcode.
- Click next to the Stop button on the Device for launching the App
- Choose "Add additional Simulators"
- Choose "Simulators"
- Click on the small plus in the bottom left
- In this screen you can choose the OS the Emulator type and also give a name for the emulator

[image: way 2 step 2]

[image: way 2 step 4-6]